# latexmk and \graphicspath

Tags: graphics, latexmk

The general problem seems to be that latexmk does not seem to work together with graphicx' `\graphicspath` directive.

I have the following directory structure:

```
├── working.tex
├── non-working.tex
├── latexmk
└── figures
    └── graph.dot
```

Running `latexmk -r latexmk -norc working.tex` compiles just fine, creates a `figures/graph.pdf` and an output pdf.

But running `latexmk -r latexmk -norc non-working.tex` yields the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `graph' not found.
```

And it also does not say

```
Latexmk: applying rule 'cusdep dot pdf figures/graph'...
Rule 'cusdep dot pdf figures/graph': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'figures/graph.pdf'
```

as the working run does.

For completeness:

```
$ latexmk --version
Latexmk, John Collins, 10 Nov 2013. Version 4.39
```

Thanks for the help.

**latexmk**:

```
# Use "bin" as output directory
$out_dir = "bin";

# Build pdf with pdflatex
$pdf_mode = 1;

# Additional options for pdflatex
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -shell-escape %O %S";

# Use pdflatex recorder functionality
$recorder = 1;

# Custom dependency to convert dot files to pdfs
add_cus_dep('dot', 'pdf', 0, 'dot2pdf');
sub dot2pdf {
    system("dot -Tpdf \"$_[0].dot\" > \"$_[0].pdf\"");
}
```

**working.tex**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{figures/graph}
\end{document}
```

**non-working.tex**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{graph}
\end{document}
```

**figures/graph.dot**:

```
digraph A {
    Test
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest work around is to create a first version of the file figures/graph.pdf by hand (e.g., by running the dot command yourself from the command line).  After that `latexmk` will detect any further changes in the `.dot` file and remake the `.pdf` file automatically when necessary.

This is obviously undesirable.

The problem is that information on the graphicspath is not in any of the relevant files that `latexmk` reads (i.e., not in either the `.log` or the `.fls` files).  Deliberately, `latexmk` doesn't examine the `.tex` file, because in general parsing `.tex` files is hard.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on why latexmk doesn't work with `\graphicspath`. Since I only have one graphics subfolder I now chose to patch my `\includegraphics` such that it automatically adds `figures/` before every file.